# inner join with multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have 2 tables TblMemberDetails,TblMemberDetailsSub am using following sql queries to fetch records
QUERY 1

```
SELECT   (TblMemberDetails.MemFname +' '+TblMemberDetails.MemMname +' '+
          TblMemberDetails.MemLname)As Name,
          TblStateMaster.StateName,
          TblDistMaster.DistName,
          TblTaluqaMaster.TaluqaName
FROM TblMemberDetails INNER JOIN TblStateMaster 
ON TblMemberDetails.StateId = TblStateMaster.StateId
INNER JOIN TblDistMaster ON TblMemberDetails.DistId = TblDistMaster.DistId 
INNER JOIN TblTaluqaMaster ON TblMemberDetails.TaluqaId = TblTaluqaMaster.TaluqaId 
INNER JOIN TblMemberDetailsSub ON TblMemberDetails.MemId = TblMemberDetailsSub.MemId
WHERE (TblMemberDetailsSub.MemMode = 'Provider')
AND (TblMemberDetailsSub.CycleStatus = 'Uncompleted') 
GROUP BY TblMemberDetailsSub.MemId, TblMemberDetails.MemId,
TblMemberDetails.MemFname, TblMemberDetails.MemMname,
TblMemberDetails.MemLname, TblStateMaster.StateName,
TblDistMaster.DistName, TblTaluqaMaster.TaluqaName
order by TblMemberDetailsSub.MemId Asc
```

QUERY 2

```
SELECT TblMemberDetailsSub.MemId, ISNULL(sum(TblMemberDetailsSub.Amount),0) AS TotalAmount,
        TblMemberDetailsSub.PayRound, TblMemberDetailsSub.PlanName
FROM TblMemberDetailsSub
WHERE (TblMemberDetailsSub.MemMode = 'Provider')
AND (TblMemberDetailsSub.CycleStatus = 'Uncompleted')
GROUP BY TblMemberDetailsSub.MemId, TblMemberDetailsSub.PayRound,
TblMemberDetailsSub.PlanName, TblMemberDetailsSub.Amount
ORDER BY TblMemberDetailsSub.MemId Asc
```

I just want both table result in single set (i user union but it is not working)
**how can i merge both queries for single result**

Comment: could you expand on "I used union but it is not working" - what does it do that is not what you want? Please include example code, and results/error code.

Comment: Both the query should have same column names and ORDER BY at last

Comment: Did you try to just union the two result together? If you want to union two results together then you need to ensure that both sides of the union have the same number of columns and same column types. It looks like you have 4 names in the top of the union and an ID, an int, and two names in the second.

Answer (score 1):

Group by in first query is not significant if you have only one row for each `memberId` in 
`TblStateMaster ,TblDistMaster ,TblTaluqaMaster` also you are not selecting any value from `TblMemberDetailsSub`  in first query . One way to merge the two queries is as follows:

```
SELECT   (TblMemberDetails.MemFname +
          ' '+
          TblMemberDetails.MemMname +
          ' '+
          TblMemberDetails.MemLname)As Name,
          TblStateMaster.StateName,
          TblDistMaster.DistName,
          TblTaluqaMaster.TaluqaName,
          T.MemId,
          T.TotalAmount,
          T.PayRound,
          T.PlanName
FROM 
TblMemberDetails 
INNER JOIN TblStateMaster ON TblMemberDetails.StateId = TblStateMaster.StateId
INNER JOIN TblDistMaster ON TblMemberDetails.DistId = TblDistMaster.DistId 
INNER JOIN TblTaluqaMaster ON TblMemberDetails.TaluqaId = TblTaluqaMaster.TaluqaId 
Inner join (
select TblMemberDetailsSub.MemId,
ISNULL(sum(TblMemberDetailsSub.Amount),0)As TotalAmount,
TblMemberDetailsSub.PayRound,
TblMemberDetailsSub.PlanName 
from TblMemberDetailsSub
WHERE (TblMemberDetailsSub.MemMode = 'Provider')
AND (TblMemberDetailsSub.CycleStatus = 'Uncompleted') 
group by TblMemberDetailsSub.MemId,TblMemberDetailsSub.PayRound,TblMemberDetailsSub.PlanName,TblMemberDetailsSub.Amount
) T ON TblMemberDetails.MemId = T.MemId
order by T.MemId Asc
```